# How to rig a bone that moves the entire object?

Tags: rigging

[image]

So what i'd like to do is use that bone to move the entire rig. Right now it is not parented with any other bone, i've just created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter Edit Mode of the armature and parent every bone that doesn't have a parent yet to your main bone with offset.